# How to get the optimized choice from arrays

Tags: ruby, algorithm, optimization, knapsack-problem

I have several arrays of hashes (let's say I have three) as follows:

```
a = [{ cost: 10, value: 20},
     { cost: 9, value: 20},
     { cost: 10, value: 22},
     { cost: 2, value: 10}
    ]

b = [{ cost: 4, value: 20},
     { cost: 9, value: 20},
     { cost: 15, value: 22},
     { cost: 12, value: 10}
    ]

c = [{ cost: 10, value: 21},
     { cost: 9, value: 20},
     { cost: 10, value: 22},
     { cost: 3, value: 10}
    ]
```

I need to find out which choice of hashes, one from each array, gives me the maximum sum of `:value` keeping the sum of `:cost` under a given value (let's say `30`).

The answer is probably easy for this case just looking at it, but this is just sample data and in reality I have many more arrays. Can someone help me or point me in the right direction?

**Edit:** I should also mention that I'd like to do with this arrays of objects. I used hashes as an example since it would be easier to describe, but I'm planning on using Objects. Also, if an Object gets used from one of the arrays, I'd like it identical options to not be used from the other arrays so each selected Object should be unique.

Comment: How many is “many more arrays”? There are simple ways to solve this that are likely to have poor performance when used on large datasets.

Comment: 8 arrays, maybe up to 50 hashes per. Performance isn't a huge issue as this would only need to run once a day.

Comment: This is a variation of the packaging problems. You should ask this as an algorithm problem, or ask at the Math site, and you will get more answers.

Comment: MM, I am preparing a solution that employs dynamic programming, which can be used efficiently for any number of arrays of hashes (i.e., not just three). I don't have time to finish it this evening, however.

Comment: Cary, that would be excellent. Would it also be possible to say, if one object gets used, remove all identical objects from the result set of all hashes, so each used object is unique to each other?

Comment: Sorry, but that requirement would move the problem into NP-complete territory. I'm curious what your application is.

Comment: 8 arrays, each containing up to 50 hashes would be a piece of cake if you used dynamic programming.  I'm guessing it would take at most a few seconds to solve.  By contrast, if you used a brute-force enumerative approach, you may well be an old man before it presents you with a solution. Also, while it may seem that adding the embellishment you mentioned should be a minor thing, it would completely wreck the mathematical structure that permits the use of dynamic programming; enumerative methods would be your only option.

Comment: Thanks Cary, it looks like the approach I'll end up using will focus heavily on weeding out combinations we know (or can assume) will never be part of the most optimal answer to get the choices more manageable. Then I check each combination for a dupe object, and find the max value from what's left. I'll post what I ended up with tonight.

Comment: I decided to add code to optimize the knapsack problem, even though you did not request it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
a.product(b,c).select{ |arr| arr.reduce(0) { |sum,h| sum + h[:cost] } < 30 }.max_by{ |arr| arr.reduce(0){ |sum,h| sum + h[:value]} }
```

Broken up a bit:

```
a.product(b,c)
 .select{ |arr| arr.reduce(0) { |sum,h| sum + h[:cost] } < 30 }
 .max_by{ |arr| arr.reduce(0) { |sum,h| sum + h[:value] } }
```

Comment: The difference between this and BroiSatse's is to do the sort first or the filtering first, and I think it is more efficient to do filter first as with BroiSatse. In your answer, you are sorting elements that would be thrown out.

Comment: Personally, I think there's a readability difference. I was trying to make the business rules are more clear. The order can be changed; I wasn't thinking of efficiency.

Comment: Also, this doesn't have the hash dependency that @MajorMajor doesn't want.

Comment: The only thing i was trying to avoid was iterating twice to calculate the sums. Unfortunately I agree it is much less readable. You can still speed up you solution a bit by changing the order of `sort_by` and `select`.

Comment: I changed the order and also noticed another improvement: I replaced `sort_by .. .last` to `max_by`.

Comment: Your solution is elegant but it does not appear as it is. I would put line breaks right before `.select` and `.max_by` and nowhere else. They are the two steps of the logic.

Comment: Thanks Mark; one last request... is there any way to remove an item from an array once it has been selected? For example, there could be the same item in b and c. If it gets used in b, I'd like it to not be used in c.

Comment: @MajorMajor If it is likely you'll need to add more rules like this  you may want to investigate a rules engine. These are nice for solving optimization problems. Some have a nice DSL to specify your rules and the engine will find the solutions that satisfy all of them.

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer as this sent me most on the right direction. As this is a brute-force approach and I was dealing with 8 arrays with ~50 combinations each, the possibilities were getting into the millions when just doing 6, so I had to add some filtering before hand like @Cary Swoveland used.  I'll make another question on optimizing my code, if anyone would be so kind! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It would be:

```
def find_max_option(max_cost, *arys)
  a = arys.shift
  a.product(*arys).map do |c| 
   [ c, c.inject({}) {|result, hash| 
       result.merge(hash) {|_,o,n| o + n }
     }
   ]
  end.select {|_,v| v[:cost] < max_cost}.max_by {|_,v| v[:value]}.first
end

find_max_option(30, a, b, c)   #=> [{:cost=>10, :value=>22}, {:cost=>4, :value=>20}, {:cost=>10, :value=>22}]
```

---

**Edit by sawa** Slightly rewritten for readability.

```
def find_max_option(max_cost, *a)
  a.first.product(*a.drop(1))
  .group_by{|hs| hs.inject({}){|acc, h| acc.merge(h){|_, v_acc, v_h| v_acc + v_h}}}
  .select{|k, _| k[:cost] < max_cost}
  .max_by{|k, _| k[:value]}
  .last.first
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, maybe you could help me a little further...

My arrays are actually arrays of objects, I just used hashes as an example to make it easier to understand. When I try to run the above code, I get the error "no implicit conversion of ObjectName into Hash". 

Could this be modified to work for an array of objects? Sorry for leaving out that detail the first time around.

Comment: Uh, that changes a lot. I tried to optimize the iterations, so all the sums are calculated in one go with merge, it can;t be done with obejcts. Have a look at @MarkThomas answer, it should be closer to what you;re looking for.

Comment: @BroiSatse Both answers given so far are brute force solutions. Is it possible to do it non-brute force? Is it NP incomplete?

Answer (score 1):

We can use dynamic programming to solve this "knapsack problem" efficiently for any number of arrays (of hashes). Solution times would be roughly proportional to the number of arrays and to the square of the average array size.

My first thought was to code this up, but then decided that would take too long and probably would not be the best way of explaining how the algorithm works.  Instead, I decided to show how an optimal solution would be computed for the example given in the question. It should be evident how the algorithm could be implemented for an arbitrary number of arrays.

**[Edit:** I decided to code this after all. I've added that at the end **tidE]**

First consider (the "last") array `c`. Here's a screen shot of the relevant information from an Excel spreadsheet.

[image]

Note that I've not included the hash at offset `0`, `{ cost: 10, value: 21}`. That's because that hash is "domninated" by the one at offset `2`, `{ cost: 10, value: 22}`.  The former could never be preferred because they both have the same cost and the latter has a higher value.

The second table shows which hash is preferred for a given "remaining budget" (i.e., after hashes in `a` and `b` have been selected). Notice that the possible remaining budget ranges from `3` (the lowest cost among the hashes in array `c`) to `24` (the total budget, `30` less the costs of choosing the hashes in `a` and `b` that have the smallest cost: `30 - 2 - 4 = 24`).

It probably would be best to implement this with an array of hashes:

```
[{budget: 3,  value: 10, hash_offset: 3 }, 
 {budget: 4,  value: 10, hash_offset: 3 },
 ...
 {budget: 8,  value: 10, hash_offset: 3 },
 {budget: 9,  value: 20, hash_offset: 1 },
 {budget: 10, value: 22, hash_offset: 2 },
 ...
 {budget: 10, value: 22, hash_offset: 2 }]
```

Now let's move on to array `b`.

[image]

Here I've only included two of the four hashes contained in array `b`, as the hash at offset `1`, `{ cost: 9, value: 20 }` is dominated by the hash at offset `0`, `{ cost: 4, value: 20 }` and the hash `{ cost: 12, value: 10}` is dominated by `{ cost: 4, value: 20}`.

Here the "available budget" ranges from `7` to `27`. `7` provides the minimum required to select one hash in `b` (at offset `0`, with cost `4`) and one in `c` (at offset `3`, with cost `3`). The high end of the range, `27`, is the maximum that could be remaining after a hash in `a` is selected (`30 - 3`).

Suppose the remaining budget (for arrays `b` and `c`) was `18`. If we were to select the hash at offset `0`, we would realize a value of `20` from that hash, and have a remaining budget of `18 - 4 => 14` for selecting a hash in array `c`. From the table for array `c` we see that we would choose the hash at offset `2` in array `c`, which has a value of `22`. We therefore would have a (maximum) value for arrays `b` and `c` of `20 + 22 => 42` if the available budget were `18` and we selected the hash at offset `0` in array `b`.

We must now consider instead selecting the hash at offset 2 in array `b`, which would yield a value of `22` and leave a remaining budget of `18 - 15 => 3` for selecting a hash in array `c`. We see from the table for array `c` that that would be the hash at offset 3, with value `10`. We therefore would have a (maximum) value for arrays `b` and `c` of `22 + 10 => 32` if the available budget were `18` and we selected the hash at offset `2` in array `b`.

It follows that if we were to have an available budget of `18` for arrays `b` and `c`, the optimum would be to select the hash at offset `0` in array `b` and at offset `3` in array `c`, for a total (maximum) value of `42`. I've outlined that choice in the table.

The same results apply for any remaining budget in the range `18 - 23`.  Similar calculations would be performed for each of the other available budget ranges. You'll see that there's a tie when the available budget is `24`.

We can now move on to array `a`. (We're almost finished.)

[image]

I've not include the hash at offset `0` because it is dominated by the hash at offset `2`.

The available budget for arrays `a`, `b` and `c` is `30`, so we do not have to condition on that (i.e. for the first array). We must consider each of three possibilities:

- choose the hash at offset `1` to earn a value of `20`, which leaves a remaining budget of `30 - 9 => 21` for arrays `b` and `c`, which (from the table for array `b`) yields an optimal value of `42` for the last two arrays, for a total value of `20 + 42 => 62`.
- choose the hash at offset `2` to earn a value of `22`, which leaves a remaining budget of `30 - 10 => 20` for arrays `b` and `c`, which (from the table for array `b`) yields an optimal value of `42` for the last two arrays, for a total value of `22 + 42 => 64`.
- choose the hash at offset `3` to earn a value of `10`, which leaves a remaining budget of `30 - 2 => 28` for arrays `b` and `c`, which (from the table for array `b`) yields an optimal value of `44` for the last two arrays, for a total value of `10 + 44 => 54`.

We therefore conclude that a maximum value of `64` is achieved by selecting the hash at offset `2` in array `a`, the hash at offset `0` in array `b` and the hash at offset `2` in array `c`.

**Code**

```
def knapsack(all_costs_and_values, total_budget)
  costs_and_values = remove_dominated_choices(all_costs_and_values)
  budget = remaining_budget(costs_and_values, total_budget)
  solution = optimize(costs_and_values, budget)
  display_solution(costs_and_values, solution)
end
```

.

```
private

def remove_dominated_choices(a)    
  a.map do |f|
    # f.invert.invert ensures that no two keys have the same value
    g = f.invert.invert
    g.each_with_object({}) do |(name,v),h|
      (h[name] = v) unless g.any? { |_,p| 
        (p[:cost] <= v[:cost] && p[:value] >  v[:value]) ||
        (p[:cost] <  v[:cost] && p[:value] >= v[:value]) }
    end
  end
end

def remaining_budget(b, tot_budget)
  mc = min_cost_per_hash(b)
  b.map.with_index do |h,i|
    if i.zero?
      (tot_budget..tot_budget)
    else
      (mc[i..-1].reduce(:+)..tot_budget - mc[0..i-1].reduce(:+))
    end
  end
end

def min_cost_per_hash(arr)
  arr.map { |h| h.values.min_by { |h| h[:cost] }[:cost] }
end
```

.

```
def optimize(costs_and_values,remaining_budget)
  solution = Array.new(costs_and_values.size)
  i = costs_and_values.size-1
  g = costs_and_values[i].sort_by { |k,v| -v[:cost] }
  solution[i] = remaining_budget[i].each_with_object({}) do |rb,h|
    name, f = g.find { |_,v| v[:cost] <= rb }  
    h[rb] = { name: name, value_onward: f[:value] }
  end
  while i > 0  
    i -= 1
    g = costs_and_values[i].sort_by { |k,v| v[:cost] }
    min_to_leave = remaining_budget[i+1].first    
    solution[i] = remaining_budget[i].each_with_object({}) do |rb,h|
      best = - Float::INFINITY
      g.each do |name, v|
        leave_for_next = rb - v[:cost]
        break if leave_for_next < min_to_leave
        candidate = v[:value] + solution[i+1][leave_for_next][:value_onward] 
        if candidate > best
          best = candidate
          h[rb] = { name: name, value_onward: candidate }
        end
      end
    end
  end
  solution      
end
```

.

```
def display_solution(costs_and_values, solution)
  rv = solution.first.keys.first
  puts "Optimal value: #{ solution.first[rv][:value_onward] }\n"
  solution.each_with_index do |h,i|
    name =  h[rv][:name]
    puts "  Best choice for hash #{i}: #{name}"
    rv -= costs_and_values[i][name][:cost]
  end
end
```

**Example**

I changed the data structure of `all_costs_and_values` to an array of hashes, with keys being labels for the cost/value pairs (e.g., `'12'` refers to what formerly was the hash at row offset `1`, column offset `2` in the OP's array). I would expect the labels to be replaced with more meaningful strings.

```
all_costs_and_values =
  [{ '00' => { cost: 10, value: 20 }, '01' => { cost:  8, value: 17 },
     '02' => { cost: 10, value: 20 }, '03' => { cost: 12, value: 24 } },
   { '10' => { cost:  6, value: 16 }, '11' => { cost:  4, value: 14},
     '12' => { cost:  6, value: 17 }, '13' => { cost:  5, value: 13 } },
   { '20' => { cost:  8, value: 16 }, '21' => { cost: 14, value: 30 },
     '22' => { cost: 16, value: 32 }, '23' => { cost: 14, value: 32 } },
   { '30' => { cost:  2, value:  4 }, '31' => { cost:  5, value:  9 },
     '32' => { cost: 10, value: 16 }, '33' => { cost:  6, value:  8 } }]

total_budget = 30

knapsack(all_costs_and_values, total_budget)
  #=> Optimal value: 70
  #     Best choice for hash 0: 01
  #     Best choice for hash 1: 12
  #     Best choice for hash 2: 23
  #     Best choice for hash 3: 30
```

In calculating the optimum, the array of hashes `solution` is constructed:

```
solution
  #=> [{  30=>{:name=>"01", :value_onward=>70}},
  #                   "01" => { cost:  8, value: 17 } leave 30-8 = 22
  #=> {14-15=>{:name=>"11", :value_onward=>34},
  #=>     16=>{:name=>"12", :value_onward=>37},
  #=>  17-18=>{:name=>"11", :value_onward=>39},
  #=>     19=>{:name=>"12", :value_onward=>42},
  #=>  20-21=>{:name=>"11", :value_onward=>50},
  #=>     22=>{:name=>"12", :value_onward=>53}},
  #                   "12" => { cost:  6, value: 17 } leave 22-6 = 16
  #=> {10-12=>{:name=>"20", :value_onward=>20},
  #=>  13-15=>{:name=>"20", :value_onward=>25},
  #=>  16-18=>{:name=>"23", :value_onward=>36},
  #                   "23" => { cost: 14, value: 32 } leave 16-14 = 2
  #=>   {2-4=>{:name=>"30", :value_onward=>4},
  #                   "30" => { cost:  2, value:  4 } leave 2-2 = 0
  #=>    5-9=>{:name=>"31", :value_onward=>9},
  #=>     10=>{:name=>"32", :value_onward=>16}}]
```