# Ruby - Optimize code finding the optimal choice from an array

Tags: ruby, arrays, optimization, knapsack-problem

I asked a question that was basically a knapsack problem - I needed to find the combination of several different array of objects that gave the optimal output. So for example, the highest sum "value" from the objects with respect to a limit on the "cost" of each object. The answer I received here was the following-

```
a.product(b,c)
.select{ |arr| arr.reduce(0) { |sum,h| sum + h[:cost] } < 30 }
.max_by{ |arr| arr.reduce(0) { |sum,h| sum + h[:value] } }
```

Which works great, but as I get into 6 arrays with ~40 choices each, the possible combinations get upwards of 4 million and take too long to process. I made some changes to the code that made processing faster -

```
#creating the array doesn't take too long
combinations = a.product(b,c,d,e)
possibles = []

combinations.each do |array_of_objects|
#max_cost is a numeric parameter, and I can't have the same exact object used twice   
if !(array_of_objects.sum(&:salary) > max_cost) or !(array_of_objects.uniq.count < array_of_objects.count)
      possibles << array_of_objects
    end
 end

  possibles.max_by{ |ar| ar.sum(&:std_proj) }
```

Breaking it into two separate arrays helped the performance a lot as I only had to check the max_by for many less possible combinations that fit the criteria.

Does anyone see a way to optimize this code? Since I'm typically dealing with tens of thousands or millions of combinations, any little bit could greatly help. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone see a way to optimize the above code to make it process faster? There are millions of possible combinations run through the code sometimes, so any little bit can help.

Comment: Where does the array comes from? Maybe you should do it in db query?

Comment: The arrays do come from a DB but they aren't the bottleneck. It's the processing in the code that is.

Comment: Your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25984485/how-to-get-the-optimized-choice-from-arrays/26003596#26003596) makes it clear that you have a knapsack problem with an extra requirement that makes it NP-complete. When it comes to optimization, "close" only counts in horseshoes. Try as you might to to be clever in how you enumerate, you cannot escape the fact that the numbers of combinations increases exponentially with both the numbers and sizes of the arrays. There's no way you can solve problems of the sizes you mentioned (8 arrays with 50 elements).

Comment: When you don't have an efficient decisive algorithm, the next best way is to use Genetic Algorithm.

Comment: @sawa, If you can't compute an optimum in a satisfactory amount of time, then by all means use heuristic methods to try to get a "good" solution. That's not what we have here, however. The code above solves a knapsack problem with no side conditions. For that, however, there is a straightforward dynamic programming solution that is far more efficient (see previous question). However, the OP wants to add an additional condition that effectively makes it impossible to obtain an optimal solution for the problem sizes of interest, yet he is not interested in heuristic methods.

Comment: @Cary I'm interested in any methods that get me the solution faster, I'm afraid I'm just not advanced enough of a programmer to write a better solution from your past answer without an actual Ruby example I can read and learn from. I'm not able to put that theory or plan into ruby code.

Comment: If you can live without extra requirement concerning duplicates (i.e., treat it as a pure knapsack problem), I'd be willing to elaborate my previous answer to provide the Ruby code, if you'd find that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If we are talking about millions of rows, and the operations are like unique and max.

I suggest you to solve it by using DISINCT and MAX() in your query and You can even use WHERE filtering by cost.

Looping over the objects in Ruby, is clearly more expensive.

Comment: The problem there is I don't have all possible combinations stored in the database, I am doing that in ruby through my product method. Do you know of something similar to generate that in a database?